# R - How to read last sheet of each excel file?

Tags: r

I have multiple excel files that I would like to read into R, however each file has differing number of sheets and I would like to read only the last sheet in each file into R, is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can first extract the number of sheets and then only access that sheet:

```
library(readxl)
sheetNr <- length(excel_sheets(filename))
read_excel(filename, sheet = sheetNr)
```